# Pattern for subclass overload with different arguments

Tags: design-patterns, python, async, python-3.x, liskov-substitution

I'm in the process of writing an bidirectional, asynchronous socket server and server handler. The base handler class I'm working off of is as follows:

```
class BaseAsyncSocketHandler:
    async def send(self, data: bytes) -> int
```

However, I want to write a subclass that sends two arguments, an event and arbitrary corresponding data, which suggests the signature:

```
   async def send(self, event: str, data: object) -> int:
       return await super().send(event_data_magic_to_bytes(event, data))
```

Unfortunately, this violates the Liskov substitution principle, and I don't think writing it as a mixin will makes the situation any better, so I'm hoping somebody has either seen this before or can think of a better design pattern (or tell me this is an unnecessary abstraction in the first place).

Comment: Does your subclass allow its users to send arbitrary bytes in addition to sending event/data combinations?

Comment: No, it wouldn't. I intended for the data bytes to consist of the packaged event and serialized object. I definitely was considering optional/keyword arguments, if that's what you were suggesting though.

Comment: Why not change the name of the method? Liskov substitution is about behavior specifications as well as signatures, but in this case, I think you are only talking about the signature.

Comment: Ultimately, this is sort of what I did. I'll add my solution below.

Comment: Why are you even using inheritance? That's the real issue here!

Comment: @gardenhead in retrospect, I think this may well be the correct "answer". I thought this would be a good way to inherit receive logic, but perhaps the better solution is to separate sending and receiving methods into two separate mixins.

Answer (score 3):

In the end, I settled on providing the following:

```
class BaseAsyncSocketHandler:

    async def _send(self, data: bytes) -> int:
        ...

    @abc.abstractmethod
    async def send(self, *args, **kwargs) -> int:
        pass
```

This way the user can implement subsets of the send method while using the base send method provided by the socket wrapper. As to why I wanted to use `send` instead of just creating another class method like `send_event`, I think I mostly just wanted the interface to the class to remain compact and usable while allowing for different socket methodologies.